# Delete part of string characters

Tags: string-manipulation, data

I have the following string dataset:

```
{{22/03 updating, 55.218 (+1.640), 44.321 (+1.640), 4.825 (+0), 6.072 (+0), details},
{21/03, 53.578 (+6.557), 42.681 (+4.821), 4.825 (+793), 6.072 (+943), details}, 
{20/03, 47.021 (+5.986), 37.860 (+4.670), 4.032 (+627), 5.129 (+689), details}, 
{19/03, 41.035 (+5.322), 33.190 (+4.480), 3.405 (+427), 4.440 (+415), details}}
```

I cleaned part of it by deleting `details` with `Drop`, but I cannot erase the brackets terms `(+...)` and the `updating` term at the same manner.
Is it possible delete `(+...)` and `updating` terms by using `Map` with some functions like `StringPartReplace` (with: `""`) or `StringDelete`, in combination with `StringCases` or similar ?

Comment: Can you show us what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many different solutions. Here is one which assumes that your inputs are either two (or more fields) separated by space, such as "22/03 updating", "55.218 (+1.640)" or a single field (such as "details") that should be ignored:

```
extract[s_String] := Module[{fields = StringSplit[s, " "]},
  If[Length[fields] > 1, First[fields], Nothing]]
```

returns

```
extract /@ {"22/03 updating", "55.218 (+1.640)", "44.321 (+1.640)", 
  "4.825 (+0)", "6.072 (+0)", "details"}
{"22/03", "55.218", "44.321", "4.825", "6.072"}
```

Just to illustrate how you can process this further (the `process` function is not very robust):

```
process[s_String] := 
 If[StringContainsQ[s, "/"], DateObject[s], ToExpression[s]]
```

[image]

The resulting list consists of a `DateObject`, followed by a list of numbers, as you can verify with `FullForm`:

```
FullForm[%]

List[DateObject[List[2020,3,22,0,0,0],"Instant","Gregorian",-7.`],
  55.218`,44.321`,4.825`,6.072`]
```

**Update**. Now that you have clarified (in comments) what specific data you are looking at, we can make the extraction more robust:

```
data = Import["https://statistichecoronavirus.it/coronavirus-italia/", "Data"];
process[s_String] := Module[{d = StringSplit[s, " "][[1]]},
  If[StringContainsQ[d, "/"], DateObject[{d <> "/2020", {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}], 
   ToExpression[StringReplace[d, "." -> ""]]]]
process[s_Integer] := s (* to process the last string *)
Map[process, data[[2, All, ;; -2]], {2}] // Dataset
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Victor! I succeded in applying the combination of the two function just for each row of my list, is it possible to apply it to the entire matrix I have?

Comment: Sure. Let's say you have a matrix `m = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 100}], 10, 10]` and a function `f` that you want to apply to each element of the matrix. Using a third optional argument of `Map`, you can apply `f` to each element of `m`: `Map[f,m,{2}]`

Comment: I don't understand if something doesn't work. I tried with `Map[extract,d,{2}]` and the result is: `{{22/03 updating, 55.218 (+1.640), 44.321 (+1.640), 4.825 (+0), 6.072 (+0), details},
{21/03, 53.578 (+6.557), 42.681 (+4.821), 4.825 (+793), 6.072 (+943), details}, 
{20/03, 47.021 (+5.986), 37.860 (+4.670), 4.032 (+627), 5.129 (+689), details}, 
{19/03, 41.035 (+5.322), 33.190 (+4.480), 3.405 (+427), 4.440 (+415), details}}

Comment: @Mick it's really hard to debug remotely :). Could you please do the following; 1) copy your definitions for `d` and `extract` into a separate notebook. 2) publish this notebook online (for free - see https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/10/24/the-new-world-of-notebook-publishing/), 3) share here as a comment - I will try to have a look

Comment: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ad9ea091-6d37-42e9-807a-2eed234de088

Comment: Everything works as expected for me: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/8f5719ca-cad9-4954-ac1f-95ecd08d87ea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105857/discussion-between-victor-k-and-mick).

Comment: Thank you Victor! At the same time, could I take into account the figures within the brackets `(+...)` by creating the related table with an other function?

Answer (score 1):

Solved - by naming the dataset `d` - with:

```
try = Table[StringExtract[Drop[d[[i]], -1], 1], {i, 1, Length[d]}]
```

I get the desidered output:

```
{{"22/03", "55.218", "44.321", "4.825", "6.072"}, {"21/03", "53.578",  "42.681", "4.825", "6.072"}, {"20/03", "47.021", "37.860", "4.032", "5.129"}, {"19/03", "41.035", "33.190", "3.405", "4.440"}}
```

Anyway, really interested in possible solutions with `Map` because I already have a list and I think should be more suitable instead of using `Table`. 
Moreover, the solution is incomplete because if, for instance, I have a string term with just one part (that is, without `(+...)`, I obtain an error on that string output.

Comment: `Table` is not the best solution, for number of reasons - it's better to define your extraction logic more clealry and use a `Map` as in my solution. Btw, `Most` returns all the elements of the list except the last one, so `Most[Range[5]]` returns `{1,2,3,4}`; it's a bit more clear than `Drop[Range[5],-1]` which accomplishes the same.